# How do I write a script to automatically optimize all the PNGs in my MediaWiki images directory?

Tags: debian, shell-script, optimization, png

I have MediaWiki 1.25.2 installed on my 64-bit Debian 8.1 VirtualBox machine and I'd like to be able to upload the `images/` directory from this installation to my DropBox. Being a cheapskate I'm trying to minimize the size of this images directory by optimizing the PNGs found therein with `optipng`, so that I don't end up with a DropBox that's so full that I need to pay for more storage. My Wiki has at the moment 182 PNGs that I have uploaded to it (along with well over a hundred others that are thumbnails of these original PNGs and of the SVGs I have on my Wiki), so running `optipng -o7 <filename>` on each of these files manually will be very tedious.

Hence I am here asking, how I might write a bash script that will automatically do this for me. Now I know some pieces of the puzzle of how to do this, like I know that the `find` program can generate lists of files with a specified file extension in a specified location (e.g., running `sudo find . -type f -name "*.png"` from the `images/` directory which for me is at `/var/lib/mediawiki/images` will list all the PNGs therein), but I don't know how to use this program to create a text file containing all the file names relative to this directory (e.g., `f/f1/Frugalware_Linux_screenshot.png`). I also don't know how to get `optipng` to optimize PNGs listed in a text file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
for i in `find . -type f -name "*.png"`
do
  optipng -o7 "$i"
done
```

Did not test it but it should work like that. If you need to test it then you might change the line `optipng -o7 $i` with `echo $i` to see if you get the correct file.

Comment: This answer is not robust at all and will already break on file names containing spaces.

Answer (score 4):

simply use `find` here:

```
find (...your filters ...) -exec optipng -o7 '{}' +
```

note that the `+` will try to use as many of `find`'s results as argument to `optipng` as possible, which is fine as this program accepts multiple files as arguments. Note that `+` only works if it is the last argument to an `-exec` command. The alternative

```
find (...filters...) -exec optipng -o7 '{}' \;
```

Will execute `optipng` once per result and thus is much slower.

Side note: `{}` in `find` stands for the file name result from your search, `-exec` will allow ececuting a command.