# How do I convert a batch of avis into mp4s?

Tags: shell-script, conversion, avconv, avi

I have several avi files in the one directory that I would like to convert to mp4s using avconv. Now I know the basic procedure of how to do this, manually, for each avi, namely (where `$@` are the variables that change with each new avi):

`avconv -i $@.avi -c copy $@.mp4`

but I was wondering if anyone knows of how to write a bash script to do this automatically. I have tried a modified version of the answer provided to my [optimizing PNG question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/223156/how-do-i-write-a-script-to-automatically-optimize-all-the-pngs-in-my-mediawiki-i) namely:

```
for k in `find . -name "*.avi"`
do
   avconv -i "$k" -c copy "$k.mp4"
done
```

but as k is of the form `./filename` avconv could not understand it when given as input. Another issue is that even though I used quotation marks, because many of my avis have spaces in their file names, for some reason avconv was being run for every space-separated word in the file's name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should loop over all `.avi` files and convert them (untested):

```
printf '%s\0' *.avi | xargs -0 -I {} -P 1 avconv -i "{}" -c copy "{}".mp4
```

You can change `-P 1` to e.g. `-P 8` to convert 8 files in parallel.